# Codeigniter - loop through post information passing value to model query and outputting result

Tags: database, codeigniter, loops, post

I have my form data being passed to the new controller/view.

I want to loop through the $_POST array, pass the value to the controller/model, query the database and return the result to the view to be displayed.

So I have the below code in my View:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) //$key is productcode eg '4560'
    {
       $this->sales_model->get_productdetails($this->input->post('$key'))
       echo "Price: ".$price."<br>";
       echo "Pieces: ".$pieces."<br>";
       echo "Cubic Meters: ".$cubicmeters."<hr>";

    }
```

This is my model:

```
function get_productdetails($productcode)
{
    $this->db->select('price,pieces,cubicmeters');
    $this->db->from('ProductList');
    $this->db->where('productcode',$productcode);
    $q = $this->db->get();
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        return $q->row_array(); 
    }
}
```

Controller:
function new_auto_spread_details() 
  {
     $this->load->view('sales/new_autospread_order_lines');
  }

This does not work correctly. How do I output/display the query results on the view? can this be done and if not how is this achieved with best practice?

Thanks as always,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use CodeIgniter's input class to get all post values.

```
$formValues = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
```

Then in your controller set an intermediate value to hold your data.

```
$products = array();

foreach($formValues as $key => $value) 
{
    $products[] = $this->sales_model->get_productdetails($key)
}

$data = array();
$data["products"] = $products;
```

Pass intermediary to the view.

```
$this->load->view('sales/new_autospread_order_lines', $data);
```

In your review reference each hashed item in the $data array as a variable.

```
<?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
<p>
    <?php echo $product["price"]; ?>
</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Randall, and how will I display this on my view? Thanks,

Comment: All hash items on the $data array become their own variables in your view.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->input->post('$key')` should be `$this->input->post($key)`

Anything beginning with `$this->` should be called by the controller, not the view.

Your controller should look something like this:

```
function new_auto_spread_details()
{
    $products = array();
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) //$key is productcode eg '4560'
    {
        /* your model method is returning an array,
           so you need to assign it to a variable */
        $products[] = $this->sales_model->get_productdetails($key)
    }

    $this->load->view('sales/new_autospread_order_lines', array(
        'products' => $products
    ));
}
```

Then in the view:

```
<?php foreach($products as $product): ?>
    Price: <?php echo $product['price'] ?><br>
    Pieces: <?php echo $product['pieces'] ?><br>
    Cubic Meters: <?php echo $product['cubicmeters'] ?><br>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Samutz, this might assist but right now the screen is blank as output is erroneous. 
`$this->sales_model->get_productdetails($this->input->post($key))` seems to break the page. can the controller be bypassed like this?

Comment: I misread the question a bit. `$this` should only be used in the controller and not the view. If you are bypassing the controller, how is the view being called?

Comment: will add controller to question now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Samutz, this is not working. if I set an echo in the controller, I can see each $key/$value. I cant however see any output in the view. any ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: @Smudger Make sure the model is loaded with `$this->load->model('sales_model'):` in the controller. Although CI/php should throw errors if it's not already loaded.